# Hibernate/JPA audit intercptor does not trigger on query updates

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have an audit interceptor very similar to this :
    http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-interceptor-example-audit-log/

Whenever i do in my service method:

```
 User user = this.userRepository.findOne(id);
 user.setX(x);
 user.setY(y);
```

I get an audit just fine! works perfect.

But when i use a query from whithin the respository like so:

```
UserRepository {

   @Query("UPDATE User u SET u.password = ?2 WHERE u.id = ?1 ")
   @Modifying
   public void updatePassword(Long userId, String encodedPassword);

}
```

The interceptor is not being called,

I really want to use this audit interceptor in case i use updates as well as standard pojo sets. 
how can i achieve it?

Thanks

Comment: [Link1](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.0.0.M1/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries) and [Link2](http://gordondickens.com/wordpress/2011/08/02/adding-queries-to-spring-data-jpa/) might help you out

Comment: you could use [hibernate envers](http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/) to do this work instead use this interceptor

Comment: envers is too "heavy duty" for my purpose

Comment: @Urbanleg have you achieved this ?

Comment: Nope,  went to a solution of auditing via db triggers.